# In ruby, I want to do a SSH connection and then perform "telnet 0" without the port and then finally a telent command grep Power

Tags: ruby, ssh, telnet

I am writting a automation test where I have to first start a SSH session, then enter telnet 0 and connect to that session using credentials and then finally inputting a command grep power and capturing the response to validate.
I tried two methods::
1)

```
Net::SSH.start(IP,
                  Username, 
                  :password => Password) do |ssh|

ssh.exec!("telnet 0")

  //login to telnet and perform the command
ssh.close
end
```

This one didnt work for me

2)

```
loginInfo = {"Name" => 'telnetUsername',
                            "Password" => 'telnetPassword',
                            "LoginPrompt" => /Username:/
                        }
        
begin
    #Define the gateway.
        objGateway = Net::SSH::Gateway.new(IP, 
                                            'SSHUsername', 
                                            :password => 'SSHPassword')
    rescue Exception => e
        
        next
    end

    #Open the telnet port.                          
        objLocalPort = objGateway.open("localhost", telnetPort)
        
    #Create telnet connection passing in the previously opened port.
    objTelnet = Net::Telnet::new("Host" => "127.0.0.1", 
                                "Port" => objLocalPort)
    #Do the telnet login.
    objTelnet.login(loginInfo)
objTelnet.cmd("grep power")
```

Now I am stuck with this one becaues I dont have a port to give in objLocalPort

If something can be modified to the above solution is greatly appreciated, or if there is something different can you please help with that and explain as well.
Thank You